# Canvas drawText, how to rotate and how to change "anchor-point"?

Tags: java, android, text, android-canvas

Good evening,

It is about an android app.

I would like to use the method Canvas.drawText(...). But I don't know how I can rotate the text. I need the text at a certain position at a certain angle. Do you know how I can achieve this?

Next question, usually the point to which the position coordinates are refering is the lower left corner. I want to change this "anchor-point" to the lower center. Is that possible? The pivot-point of the rotation should be the same.

I guess simple questions, but I don't know how to do this. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

here is a basic example of drawing text on a path, to get it how you want you should mess with the path and the paint [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html), [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html)

```
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Path path = new Path();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    path.moveTo(canvas.getWidth()/2, 0);
    path.lineTo(canvas.getWidth()/4, 400);
    canvas.drawTextOnPath("text manipulated", path, 0, 0, paint);
```